# Filepicker won't start

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winui-3, filepicker

I've been trying to initialize this picker for three days now. In the code the line "var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);" causes the error "System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."". What should I do:

```
    public sealed partial class uploadingUVPage : Page
    {
        public uploadingUVPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void PickAFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Clear previous returned file name, if it exists, between iterations of this scenario
            PickAFileOutputTextBlock.Text = "";

            // Create a file picker
            var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

            // Retrieve the window handle (HWND) of the current WinUI 3 window.
            var window = WindowHelper.GetWindowForElement(this);
            var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);

            // Initialize the file picker with the window handle (HWND).
            WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(openPicker, hWnd);

            // Set options for your file picker
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

            // Open the picker for the user to pick a file
            var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                PickAFileOutputTextBlock.Text = "Picked file: " + file.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                PickAFileOutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have already copied WindowNative and WindowHelper

Comment: What's `WindowHelper.GetWindowForElement(this)` ? Where does this come from?

Comment: @SimonMourier I think that is the [helper class](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/398af50b49909bcc3ef180bb81006ffa7bc406ac/WinUIGallery/Helper/WindowHelper.cs) used in the WinUI 3 Gallery app. It's very confusing.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding - indeed :-)