# using HWND for Pages in WinUI 3 C#

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I've been trying to initialize filepicker for the 3rd day in a row. In the empty project I was able to implement the window handle in the window, but in my project the page is protruding. How do I implement a window handle for a page?

Here is my code

```
    public sealed partial class uploadingUVPage : Page
    {
        public uploadingUVPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void PickAFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a file picker
            var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

            // Retrieve the window handle (HWND) of the current WinUI 3 window.
            IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);

            // Initialize the file picker with the window handle (HWND).
            WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(openPicker, hWnd);

            // Set options for your file picker
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

            // Open the picker for the user to pick a file
            var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                PickAFileOutputTextBlock.Text = "Picked file: " + file.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                PickAFileOutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";

            }
        }
    }
```

first i tried the initialization from winui 3 gallery

```
    var window = WindowHelper.GetWindowForElement(this);
    var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
```

but later i replaced it with

```
 IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
```

Comment: Your question has already been tagged as a dupliacte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162079/filepicker-wont-start, explain why it's not a duplicate or it will be closed again

Comment: @SimonMourier in the last question I asked why I can’t initialize, but now I’m asking how to initialize ON THE PAGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of `Window` to `GetWindowHandle`.

But in this line,

**uploadingUVPage.cs**

```cs
// Retrieve the window handle (HWND) of the current WinUI 3 window.
IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
```

you are passing **this**, which is an instance of `uploadingUVPage`.

What you need to do is to get the instance of your `Window`, which is the `MainWindow` instantiated in **App.xaml.cs** when you create a plain WinUI 3 project.

One way to do this:

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static Window Window { get; } = new MainWindow();

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Window.Activate();
    }
}
```

then:

**uploadingUVPage.cs**

```cs
// Retrieve the window handle (HWND) of the current WinUI 3 window.
IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(App.Window);
```